# ASP.Net Javascript integration

Tags: asp.net, javascript

I am trying to use the following script in asp.net:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    function checktext() {
        var txt = document.getElementById('tbComments');

        if (txt.Text.Length > 0) {
            alert('Thank you for submitting feedback.');

            return true;
        }
        else {
            alert('Sorry, you must enter text before submitting.')

            return false;
        }
    }
</script>


    <asp:Button ID="btnSave" runat="server" Text="Submit" onclick="btnSave_Click" OnClientClick="checktext();" />
```

I have tried using it on the onclick event.. the script will just not work at all.

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use the ClientID property for getting the name of a Control on the client side. I suggest you to try jQuery for all these though

```
var txt = document.getElementById('<%=tbComments.ClientID%>');
```

besides, the OnClientClick has to receive a true or false value, in order to "know" whether to send the request to the server; so you have to change it with something like `OnClientClick="return checktext();"`

Comment: Compiler Error Message: CS1061: 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox' does not contain a definition for 'ClientId' and no extension method 'ClientId' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: You have to write ClientID , with a capital D at the end

Answer (score 0):

Try calling it like this:

```
<asp:Button 
    ID="btnSave" 
    runat="server" 
    Text="Submit" 
    onclick="btnSave_Click" 
    OnClientClick="return checktext();" />
```

Also this line looks suspicious in a web forms application:

```
document.getElementById('tbComments');
```

Make sure that the generated id of your control is not prefixed with something else.

Answer (score 0):

Replace:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnSave" runat="server" Text="Submit" onclick="btnSave_Click" OnClientClick="checktext();" />
```

with:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnSave" runat="server" Text="Submit" onclick="btnSave_Click" OnClientClick="return checktext();" />
```

Replace:

```
var txt = document.getElementById('tbComments');
```

With:

```
var txt = document.getElementById('<%= tbComments.ClientId %>');
```

HTH.

Comment: ClientId is not part of a text box it says.

Comment: Should be tbComments.ClientID

Answer (score 0):

everone else mentioned OnClientClick so I won't address that.

assuming tbComments is a textbox of some kind, this line

```
if (txt.Text.Length > 0) {
```

is going to fail because Text is not a property of html inputs or textareas, which is how asp.net textboxes are rendered. what you want is

```
if (txt.value.length > 0) {
```

also, is there some reason you're not using a regular asp.net RequiredFieldValidator control? you're doing more work than you need to. If you absolutely have to have alert boxes, you can use a CustomValidator control to call your function (you'll have to tweak it to fit the model).

Comment: Validator! very nice. But the javascript problem still intrigues me.